# Github Pages error: yaml file query returns an empty file

Tags: github-pages

I have a static website repo hosted with Github Pages. The javascript must load two text files (`.yml` files more precisely) stored in that same repo in a `data` folder. The functions used to load the two files are the following:

```js
async function readTextFile(path) {
    console.log("Path:", path);
    const response = await fetch(path);
    console.log("Response:", response);
    const text = await response.text();
    console.log("Text:", text);
    return text;
}
export async function loadBodiesData() {
    const content = await readTextFile("./data/kspbodies.yml");
    /* Some post processing */
}
export async function loadConfig() {
    const content = await readTextFile("./data/settings.yml");
    /* Some post processing */
}
```

The `kspbodies.yml` file is correctly loaded and its content displayed in the console (`Text: ...`). The `settings.yml` file however appears to be empty (`Text: <empty string>`). The file exists as a direct look at this file from its URL doesn't throw a 404 error, but returns an empty file (0 byte size).

- Here is the live demo : https://krafpy.github.io/KSP-MGA-Planner/ (open the dev console)
- The source repo : https://github.com/Krafpy/KSP-MGA-Planner/tree/yaml-load-fail

  - `kspbodies.yml` and `settings.yml` are located in `/data`
  - the code above is located in `/dist/main/utilities/data.js` and are called from `/dist/main/main.js`

### What I have tried

- Waiting for several hours in case it was needed for all files to be "detected"
- Renaming `settings.yml` into something else
- Creating a new file with the same content as `settings.yml`, its URL returns an empty file as well

Note: The website works perfectly on a local server.

Does anyone know where this problem comes from and how to fix it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I found the problem.
It actually comes from the syntax used in the yaml files. The first characters in the file seem to matter. I experimented with the content of a YAML file and here are the results when loaded through the hosted github page:

- Simplest content: **loads correctly**

```yaml
test: 42
```

- Added `---` and `...` as documented in the [Wikipedia page for YAML](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML): **loads an empty file**

```yaml
---
test: 42
...
```

- Added a comment before the `---`: **loads correctly**

```yaml
# Test file
---
test: 42
...
```

So it seems that having a YAML file starting with `---` makes the content of the file being ignored by the server. There is probably a difference in syntax standards used between github servers and vscode live server for yaml files.